# Why canvas.setBitmap() hides other views in Parent?

Tags: android, canvas, ondraw

I have this class that extends `View`:

```
public class DrawingPanel extends View {

    private Bitmap toDisk;
    private int w;
    private int h;

    public DrawingPanel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        System.out.println("Drawing");
        p0 = new Paint();
        p0.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        toDisk = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawPath(path0, p0);
        canvas.setBitmap(toDisk);

    }

}
```

I use this class as a child view in a layout. In the `Graphical view` of Eclipse all things are OK, and all views are visible, but in emulator my class (`DrawingPanel`) hides other views that are below it. When I remove this line:

```
canvas.setBitmap(toDisk);
```

all views will be visible again. And another strange thing: when I put that line in the first line of `onDraw` method like this:

```
@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                canvas.setBitmap(toDisk);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawPath(path0, p0);
    }
```

my `DrawingPanel` and other views that are below it will be invisible. How can I solve this problem?
**My purpose is to save what user draws on canvas.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand setBitmap.  It sets a bitmap for you to send new draw commands to INSTEAD OF the screen.  It does not draw the previous commands to a bitmap.  To do that, you'd want to do this:

```
Canvas diskCanvas = new Canvas(toDisk);
//Send all draw commands to this canvas
screenCanvas.drawBitmap(toDisk, new Matrix(), new Paint());
```

Note that this will only save the bitmap to memory.  To save to disk, you need to save it to a file.  Do NOT do that in onDraw, its a slow operation.